# Planner for Car-Like Robot

Tags: navigation, moveit, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let me begin by saying that I have done my obligatory "google-ing" and I know there has been discussion, but I have not found a satisfactory answer and therefore I am asking here ...

I am trying to come up with a solution for path planning for a large, custom UGV (essentially a drive-by-wire utility vehicle). I understand that the ros nav packages generally do not support "Ackermann steering" vehicles. I would like to solicit opinions on how I should proceed, here are a couple paths forward that I can see ...

1. Write custom base_local_planner and base_global_planners which take into account the kinematic constraints of an Ackermann steering vehicle
2. Use a library like MoveIt (is this even possible?)
3. Start from scratch and ditch move_base and everything inside

I see blog posts and such of people using ROS on their steered vehicles, but the documentation of such systems seems to be lacking. Any advice would be well appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217091/planner-for-car-like-robot/) by [baronep](https://answers.ros.org/users/23631/baronep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2015-09-04

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljxiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/26431/ljxiang/) on 2016-03-30**:
Hi, would you have solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest writing global and local planners that support an Ackermann vehicle. You'll have to extend move_base so that it can publish AckermannDriveStamped messages to ackermann_cmd instead of publishing Twist messages to cmd_vel. You might want to write some recovery behaviors that will work with an Ackermann vehicle.

---

Originally posted by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) with karma: 792 on 2015-09-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest you check the [Ackermann Group](http://wiki.ros.org/Ackermann%20Group)  page. The discussion about controlling an Ackermann vehicle has been going on for some time now and I'm sure you can find lots of useful resources there.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2015-09-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [baronep](https://answers.ros.org/users/23631/baronep/) on 2015-09-08**:
I have been monitoring this interest group and it doesn't look like there has been any movement in the past year.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So since posting this question, one of the base local planners has been extended to incorporate the kinodynamic constraints associated with an ackermann drive vehicle. Check out

[TEB_LOCAL_PLANNER](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner)

I have not managed to get it running too robustly but that may just be a problem with my configuration. Good luck

---

Originally posted by [baronep](https://answers.ros.org/users/23631/baronep/) with karma: 106 on 2016-03-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) on 2016-04-01**:
thanks for suggesting the planner ;-)
I am going to improve the support of carlike robots in a few weeks (april/may). Currently the planner assumes a circular robot for collision avoidance, which is often not the case (especially for carlike robots). But you might give it a try even now.

Cheers